# iOS Swift - Passing data from First ViewController to Third ViewConTroller

Tags: swift, segue

For example, my app has 3 ViewControllers: **A, B, C**
I use Segue to move **A->B->C**. My problem is that at ViewController **C**, I want to get directly data of ViewController **A**, without passing data from **A->B**, then **B->C**. 
Is it possible?

For more detail: I made **a form with many steps** (**Step A->B->C then submitting**). So at the final step, **I want to collect all user's input at each step and submit them.**

How can I get all data at the final step?

- *1. Store data temporarily somewhere then getting at final step*
- *2. At final step, directly getting data of each step by some magic?*

Comment: Just pass the data when you are segueing from A to C ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a segue between `A` and `C`.

Then in `A` view controller, check the `destination` view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let aVC = segue.destination as? aVC {
        // pass data to A view controller
    } else if let bVC = segue.destination as? bVC {
        // pass data to B view controller
    }
```

**EDIT**

If you want to share form data betwwen view controller `A`, `B` and `C`, you could create a `Signleton` Class and set all the form data in a variable:

```
class FormData {
    static let shared = FormData()

    private init() {}

    var formData: String = "variable containing the form data"
}
```

And to get the form data in the view controller `C`, use:

```
let myFormData = FormData.shared.formData
```

Comment: For detail: my case is that I separated a form into many steps (such as A,B,C... steps), User must go through step by step, then submitting his/her information at final step. So my ViewController C is final step, is your solution suitable for this case? (Sorry if something's ambiguous)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `NavigationController` you can access each controller pushed to it directly through it by addressing it's `viewControllers[index]`.

For example you can use a custom `NavigationController` by overriding the default class and store each step's data in it which is accessible by all of view controllers pushed inside it and in C you can retrieve them like this:

```
let navVC = self.navigationController as? YourCustomNavigationController
let data = navVC.getData()
```

or just save data temporarily in `AppDelegate` and it will be accessible anywhere in your app which is not recommended because it makes your code dirty

If it was not helpful please give me more information about your app structure and what are you trying to do :)

---

Create a new cocoa touch class and name it like : `CustomNavigationController` and make it **subclass** of `UINavigationController` and if you are using a storyboard set the navigation controller class which **A** is pushed into it to `CustomNavigationController` (under identity inspector tab) in Interface builder

Then you can add your properties and methods to `CustomNavigationController` like :

```
var data : AnyObject?

func storeData(data:AnyObject){

}

func getData() -> AnyObject? {
    return data
}
```

And from any view controller of it pass the value to Navigation Controller :

```
let navVC = self.navigationController as! CustomNavigationController
        navVC.storeData(data: myData)
    }
```

Comment: can you show me how to "Use a custom NavigationController by overriding the default class and store each step's data in it". I think it will help me a lot. Thank you!